# find least among the loop of queues

Tags: c++, loops, struct, queue

I have a loop of queues (`n` number of queues), I want to search all the size of queues and find least size queue.

I just thought of a logic

```
std::queue<int> q;
/* fill queue ... */
int min_value = INT_MAX;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( q=2; q=n; q++){ // from the second queue to the end queue
if
 min_value=min.size() > q.size()?
 q.size()=min_value
```

Is this logic correct, I am not sure about it, can someone please help me out!

**Edited**: i tried to figure out

```
std::queue<int> q;
    /* fill queue ... */
    int min_value = INT_MAX;
    std::size_t size = q.size();
    for( q=0; q<n; q++){ // given loop of queues
    if
    (q.size()<min_value) // q.size() is compared with the min_value (limits MAX)
    min_value=q.size(); // any value of my q.size() which is less than INT_MAX will initially be declared the minimum value. On subsequent iterations this value is refined -- if a smaller value is found that's used for future iterations. at the end of loop, i will get the least value.
```

is this logic correct?

Comment: It's hard to say if your logic is correct since there are many syntax errors. Please post something that compiles at least.

Comment: oh yeah, but can u say jus the logic how to compare the size of each queues and get minimum, then i can workout with the syntaxes

Comment: @interjay http://architects.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-minimum-and will this logic works out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors:

1. Arrays in most languages including `c++` are zero indexed so probably the cycle should be:

   ```
   for( q=0; q<n; q++){
   ```

   NOTE: your condition `q=n` is completely pointless and will cause infinite loop.
2. In the cycle use `min_value` not `min.size` which has no meaning.
3. In the cycle and before it access queues by index. I suggest you keep the queues in a vector, so this would be:

   ```
   std::vector<std::queue<int> > q;
   ```

   And you access a given queue's size using `q[i].size()`.

Comment: okay, i can initialize the queue to 0 and start looping and as u said use the queues with a vector will be a great idea, but i need the logic how to compare each of the queue sizes and store it in the min_value. do you have any idea of this logic alone?

Comment: Well as you showed in your code: `std::queue` has a method `size()` make use of it.

Comment: will the comparison like this, http://architects.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-minimum-and of each size,give the minimum size?

Comment: @user1983117 sure. It seems like the way one compute min element.

Comment: is it possible to do like this min_value=std::min_element(q[i].size());

Comment: No. min_element expects a range specified by two iterators. Easiest way to solve your problem is to write the cycle as you did in the question.

Comment: @Ivyalo Strandjevif min_value=min_value.size()> q[i].size()

 q[i].size()=min_value; 
so this logic will be correct? pls help me out i am new to c++

Comment: This question you are asking is not `C++` related and its very,very basic programming question. I really don't feel I should be answering it. Moreover I see no way to answer this question without giving you the whole solution for your problem, which will definitely do you no good.

Comment: @ivyalostrandjevokay if i call the min_value.size() function, which values would it get?..! min values have the values with limits of MAX. so which value would it be assigned to this function..!

Comment: `min_value` is an integer so you can not call a **method** on it like `size()`, luckily for you you only care about its value. So instead of doing `min_value.size()`, simply use `min_value` (no method call).

Comment: @ivaylostrandjevokay if i do the operation min_value> q.size(), what values will min_value gets assigned, will it dynamically change in each iteration and compare with the queue.size()

Comment: No you need to do a check and an assignement: `if (min_value > q.size()) min_value = q.size();`

Comment: @ivaylovstrandjev i edited my question with a new logic., pls check whether it can be done like that

Comment: @ivaylovstrandjevif (min_value > q.size()) min_value = q.size();  yes i understood, each time min_value is updated for the loop and checks each time and atlast we will get the least size, am i right ?

Comment: @user1983117: Programming is not about writing something up then asking other people "is this right?" You need to figure it out on your own. Go grab a book, talk to your professor, etc., whatever you need to do to complete *your* own work.